# Google Load balancer vs httpd apache load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

We use apache httpd load balancer for our project.

We were looking at Google Load balancer and may be shift to it.

But i dont find any comparison of both as in pro/con of one over another, so that we can decide on what suits as best.
**Can we get a list of pro/con?**

Answer (score -1):

If scalability and performance is critical to you, definitely choose GCE load balancer. The traditional model of load balancing is basically "proxy + backends", in which the proxy quickly becomes the bottleneck. This is not the case for GCE load balancer, which has no proxy at all, the load balancing is implemented by the underlying infrastructure.

But GCE load balancer is not free, see pricing here https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#lb.